# EntityManagerFactory with zero entities in metamodel

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am developing an Java EE application with WildFly web server. For some reasons I need to recreate EntityManagerFactory, but after creation count of entities in metamodel is zero.
here is my code:

```
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "xx");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "xx");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");

properties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class");

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("dynamicPU", properties);
EntityManager dynamicEm = emf.createEntityManager();
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="dynamicPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

anybody knows what's going on?

Comment: We need more details on what you're trying to do. You've got your `persistence.xml` set to use `JTA` which requires the `EntityManager` to be managed by the container.

Comment: Thank you James, my application is something like form designers. I need to create new tables at run time in my DB. I checked  RESOURCE_LOCAL but has same result too.